# If $x\in \Bbb{Q}$ then $x^2=2$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation

If $x ∈ Q$ and $x = \sup\{q ∈ Q | q > 0, q^2 < 2\}$ then $x > 0$ and $x^2 = 2$.

Proof: Let $E$ equal the set on the right hand side, and suppose $x \in Q$ such that $x = \sup E$. Then, since $1 \in E$
and $x$ is an upper bound for $E$, $1 \le x \implies x > 0$.
We now prove that $x^2 \ge 2$. Suppose that $x^2 < 2$.
Define $h=\min\left\{0.5,\frac{(2-x^2)}{2(2x+1)}\right\}$.
I am curious why $h$ is defined as it is and how did author derived it?
Especially why is there $1/2$? And why compare it with$ \frac{(2-x^2)}{2(2x+1)}$? To me $ \frac{(2-x^2)}{2(2x+1)}$ is derived from $(x+h)^2<2$ but $1/2$ looks randomly chosen number between $1$ and $0$.

Isn't the expression in x inside min{} already less than 1?

Additional source file if the post sounds confusing. Theorem 14 of  https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-100a-real-analysis-fall-2020/resources/mit18_100af20_lec33/

Comment: What do you want to prove? $x^2=1$ or $x^2=2$?

Comment: And the statement $x^2=2$ can't be true for $x\in \mathbb Q\,.$

Comment: The set can not have a supremum.

Comment: Well, it can't have a supremum *in* $\mathbb{Q}$. It does have a supremum in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @KurtG. $x^2=2$ we suppose $x\in Q$ we are not proving $x^2=2$ is irrational. Please read it carefully thank you :).

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to prove that if $x\in \mathbb Q$ and $x^2\ge 2$, then $x^2 > 2$?

Comment: @ryaron we are not trying to verify whether antecedent is true or false.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you're proving it or not; if $x^2 = 2$, then $x$ is irrational and not in $\mathbb{Q}$. And you never get around to proving $x^2$ is actually equal to $2$; you only start proving $x^2 \geq 2$, and then it seems you have gotten stuck there. ¶ In short, the proposition as you have stated it in your fist line isn't true. If it starts "If $x \in \mathbb{R}\ldots$" the statement is true and can be proved.

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-100a-real-analysis-fall-2020/resources/mit18_100af20_lec53/ here is source file the bottom one is the theorem if there is any misunderstanding.

Comment: Because the antecedent is always false, nonsensical statements such as "If $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x = \operatorname{sup}\{q \in \mathbb{Q} \mid q > 0, q^2 < 2\}$, then pigs are blue" are also true. What's the point?

Comment: @BrianTung Whether antecedent is true or false doesn't matter what matters is the whole implication statement. You might not know if antecedent is true or false in some cases but you can verify if the implication is true.

Comment: Where is this proposition you're trying to prove in that file? I don't see it anywhere in there.

Comment: Maybe you have the wrong link.

Comment: @BrianTung sorry here is correct link https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-100a-real-analysis-fall-2020/resources/mit18_100af20_lec33/ theorem 14

Comment: Yeah, that context would have been much more useful. It would then be abundantly clear that this theorem is on the way to proving that it has no supremum in $\mathbb{Q}$. You should put this in your original post ASAP. It makes no sense without it, especially as you refer to "the author" and $h$, which are nowhere referenced in the rest of your post.

Comment: @Curious Mind, yes the antecedent is false, but can you prove the consequent is true? Otherwise the sentence is false.

Comment: @ryaron the consequent is true. My question was why h=min{1/2, formula}<1 and not h={1, formula} or other why there is 1/2? Isn't 1/2 redundant? To me it looks like say 2<3 and author just write 2<3+1 . I hope there is reason to this and I am wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After looking at those lecture notes, it's true that I find no good reason for the $1/2$, or indeed to take a minimum with any value. The author does not appear to use that cap anywhere.

Comment: Same here but little bit different. I think author could write h=min{1,formula} or h=formula<1. No need to complicate thing. For the time being I accept this answer. Until someone could prove this answer wrong.

Comment: I would like to know the reason why this answer is downvoted. Is there any reason? Does the downvoter know the answer? Would really appreciate the reasoning.

Comment: @CuriousMind: Honestly, who knows? People down-vote for any number of reasons. It doesn't happen very often to me, so I don't really waste too much time thinking about it. Of course, if the down-voter comes back and adds an explanatory comment, then I may change my answer if I think the feedback is useful.